# Skyrim quests/items/place names in other languages

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I pre-loaded Skyrim through Steam before release date and it has installed by default using my native language (Italian). The translation has a good quality so I decided to keep it and not switch to English.

Now I am encountering some problem when asking for help here because obviously quests but also some items/places names are different.

Are there any files inside Skyrim installation that I can use to understand how English terms have been localized to my language?

I checked the folder structure and found a folder called

> \steamapps\common\skyrim\Data\Strings\

It contains various *.strings, *.DLStrings and *.ILStrings files with promising sizes, but they are encoded in some way and unusable in this state.

Comment: There are some tools out there to convert the string files. Check out this site: http://sites.google.com/site/jpmodfiles/localize/skyrim the Strings File Tool converts the text data files (STRINGS, DLSTRINGS, ILSTRINGS) to CSV format (UTF-8). The XlsImport tool is for merging the data into a CSV/Excel file for better management. There's literally over ten thousand lines of text data, managing them within multiple sheets helps a bit. There's some command line involved. If that's not your thing, try this: http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=165 , requires MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tools to convert the String files:

Check out this [site](http://sites.google.com/site/jpmodfiles/localize/skyrim). The Strings File Tool (.requires NET Framework 4) converts the text data files (STRINGS, DLSTRINGS, ILSTRINGS) to CSV format (UTF-8).

The XlsImport tool is for merging the data into a CSV/Excel file for better management. There's literally over tens thousand lines of text data, managing them within multiple sheets helps a bit.

There's some command line involved. Here is a brief explanation of how to use the packer and unpacker:

`StringsUnpacker /DL [DLSTRINGS file to unpack] [Output filename and extension]`
`StringsUnpacker /IL [ILSTRINGS file to unpack] [Output filename and extension]`
`StringsUnpacker [STRINGS file to unpack] [Output filename and extension]`

The packer works the same way.

E.g., `StringsPacker [Filename and extension of data you want to pack] [STRINGS file to pack to]`

There's a readme file in each of the two zip files that go into more details (in Japanese, sorry) on the commands and format.

If that's not your thing, try [this utility](http://skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=165), requires MSVC (chances are you already have this installed).

Comment: Thank you, that String File Tool is nice, and I suppose that it can do half-work, STRINGS files are much more readable now. What I miss is a reference to the English text so that I can match the original one and the localized version. I already tried Skyrim Viewer, but it does not help at the moment, or at least I didn't understand how to use properly to solve my issue.

Comment: I believe you can match the English text dialogue with that of the localized version, by the text ID (e.g., 000000B2: Citizens of Skyrim, they are a tall and fair-haired people[...]). The Skyrim Viewer was made for inspecting the structure of Skyrim's ESPs, ESMs, and string files, so it probably wasn't meant for localization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the folder

```
<Steam>\steamapps\common\skyrim\Data\Interface
```

I have Skyrim in English so i can't be sure, but there is a file that is called translation_english.txt there. This file has lots of strings that is translated from english to english. So i imagine that a italian installation would have Italian to English translations.

Comment: There is a file listed there but it is really small. I checked now the folder structure and there is a folder called <Steam>\steamapps\common\skyrim\Data\Strings\. The size of files inside these folder is promising but they seems encoded in some way.

Answer (score -1):

For translate the menus:

```
<Steam>\steamapps\common\skyrim\Data\Interface
```

For all the history and books:

```
<Steam>\steamapps\common\skyrim\Data\Strings
```

Which this last folder contains very large files. For edit must change the last "*.strings" or "*.DLStrings" with, for example, "*.txt".